# ¿ Para que sirve utilizar el signo __ en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estaba viendo el form del login de laravel y veo que utiliza estos caracteres __
ejemplo {{ __('Email') }} y eh buscado pero no encuentro del porque.

Digo solo es curiosidad pero no me quiero quedar con la duda, gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es un acceso rápido a traducir las cadenas como indican en la documentación:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#retrieving-translation-strings

`{{__('Username')}}` será transformado a su idioma coincidiendo en la llave del archivo `resources/lang/xx.json`, siendo xx el idioma en iso

Por ejemplo imaginemos este archivo es.json:

```
   {
   'Username': 'Nombre de Usuario'
   };
```

En la vista aparecerá `Nombre de Usuario`en vez de `Username`

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Cabe aclarar que debe configurarse el idioma en el config app.php